# itext code for align justify not working in java file when new line character used

Tags: java, itext

code:

```
paragraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
paragraph.add(new Paragraph("        Prospective user has to see all the Excel Documents, save without renaming it,\n        fill the rates and save without renaming it  and then upload the same.\n"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out (based on the comments posted to my previous answer), the goal was to organize content in a tabular form. Using white space isn't a good solution to achieve this.

The problem was solved by using a `PdfPTable` and `PdfPCell` objects:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
PdfPCell cell13a = new PdfPCell(
    new Phrase("13"));
sectionII.addCell(cell13a);
PdfPCell cell13b = new PdfPCell(
    new Phrase("Last date and time of closing of online submission of application"));
sectionII.addCell(cell13b);
PdfPCell cell13c = new PdfPCell(
    new Phrase("(17:00 Hrs.) "));
cell13c.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
sectionII.addCell(cell13c);
```

Answer (score 0):

First this: [doesn't work is not a problem description that a software developer should give when asking a question on an internet forum. That's a problem description most commonly employed by standard users that do not understand or care about how computers work.](http://lowagie.com/doesntwork)

You claim that this doesn't work:

```
paragraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
paragraph.add(new Paragraph("        Prospective user has to see all the Excel Documents, save without renaming it,\n        fill the rates and save without renaming it  and then upload the same.\n"));
```

If assume that you are complaining about the correct behavior of iText, more specifically, you are probably complaining about the fact that the last line in each paragraph delimited by a newline is not justified.

That is expected behavior: read any book with justified text, and you will see that this is normal behavior. Books in which every line is justified, even the last line of a paragraph are ugly and hard to read.

Nevertheless, you can ask iText to show that behavior. If you want to create an ugly output like that, you need to use `ALIGN_JUSTIFIED_ALL` instead of `ALIGN_JUSTIFIED`:

```
paragraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED_ALL);
paragraph.add(new Paragraph("        Prospective user has to see all the Excel Documents, save without renaming it,\n        fill the rates and save without renaming it  and then upload the same.\n"));
```

**Update:**

In a comment, you now say: "I want to make justify with in case: new lines in between paragraph with white spaces at start of the line for huge amount of data. I don't want to justify the last line of a paragraph."

This is very unclear. Moreover: using the space character to add extra white space is a bad idea. I think you want to use a `Separator`, but your question is so unclear that it can't be answered in its current form.

Comment: sorry if I caused any misunderstanding in question.Really i want to make justify with in case: new lines in between paragraph with white spaces at start of the line for huge amount of data. I dont want to justify the last line of a paragraph.. @ Mr.Bruno Lowagie

Comment: Have you tried using non-breaking spaces for the white space? Also: are you sure you aren't asking for tabs? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: @HarishSelvaraj There might be a misunderstanding concerning the term "paragraph". For Bruno *paragraphs* here are the largest text sequences which are only broken across lines if there is not enough space left, not because of some hard line break. Thus, Your inner `Paragraph` object contains two *paragraphs*, "Prospective user has to see all the Excel Documents, save without renaming it," and "fill the rates and save without renaming it  and then upload the same." And as those paragraphs are one-liners, each is completely subject to the last-line-is-not-justified alignment exception

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thanks for your suggestion but i made my entire document content within two column table structure(1st.column for serial number and 2 column for contents). Which provides good look...

Comment: @HarishSelvaraj If you want a two-column structure, then why didn't you use a table with two columns. Oh wait, I know: you are looking for another job and you want to make your successor's job hell by writing an application he or she will never be able to maintain.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie * i have attached a piece of code of a row to get that format. if any enhancement please let me know *  PdfPCell cell13a = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("13"));
                PdfPCell cell13b = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Last date and time of closing of online submission of application"));
                PdfPCell cell13c = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("(17:00 Hrs.) "));
                cell13c.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
                sectionII.addCell(cell13a);
                sectionII.addCell(cell13b);
                sectionII.addCell(cell13c);

Comment: Code in a comment is hard to read, you should update your question instead. I'll do this in your place for once. I still don't understand the problem, though.

Comment: My question was how to justify a paragraph, when the next line character is used inside a paragraph. But that was totally wrong idea. Instead i used all paragraph data with table structure.

Comment: OK, so you have solved your problem. That wasn't clear. I'll move your comment to an answer.